# How to read a number into "subnumbers"?

Tags: c, console, modulo

So what I mean by that is that I want to read let's say the number 1234 into four other numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4. Now I know about the % operator and how to do this but the number from the console might be up to 100 digits long and from what I know this far you can't store such a big number in memory.

So here comes the real question:

> How can I read its digit on each own from the console without having to read the whole number and then separate it using the modulo?
>
> Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Don't read a _number_ but a _string_. Then you have acces to each character and may convert it to an integer number: `int i = c - '0'`

Comment: I mean if it is possible to read one digit at a time!? So on 1234 read 1 separated from 2 and 3 and 4!!

Comment: "you can't store such a big number in memory" -- By using arbitrary precision arithmetic we can represent much larger numbers than that... Consider playing around with [this web calculator](https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm).

Answer (score 3):

1. Use either `getc()` in a loop for every single character or `fgets()` to read the whole line as a string.
2. for each character, subtract `'0'` to convert the ascii code to the decimal number (optionally checking for valid range between `'0'` and `'9'` if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x;

    while ( scanf( "%1d", &x ) == 1 ) printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}
```

If to enter

```
0123456789
```

the the program output will be

```
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
x = 8
x = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the number you want to be separated is in the variable i,

```
int i;
char buffer [100];
int num[100];
sprintf(buffer,"%d",i);

int n;
for(n=0;buffer[n]!='\0';n++){
num[n]=buffer[n]- '0';       //Converting ASCII character to integer
}
```

Now we get the integer i separated into it's individual member numbers in array num[]

Don't forget to include following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: The question specifically stated that it is possible that the number is greater than what will fit in any standard integer data type.